# How to find a hidden code in a wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, null, popup, themes, code-cleanup

I have developed and published a wordpress website and I used a nulled theme (Business Lounge). After publish it into google suddenly I noticed there are pop up advertisements and push notifications are showing. I can Inspect the advertisement element. But I can't locate the source code from wp files. please help me to locate and delete the advertisement pop ups. also really appreciate if anyone can tell me how to figure out the push notifications code to modify/disable.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tv9Gs.png)

Answer (score -1):

It's very bad idea to use nulled thems and plugins, and this issue you have is one of the reasons why.
But if you insist, you can use  php malware scanner :

https://github.com/scr34m/php-malware-scanner

NB : this tool may report some false positives, so you gonna have to be sure that the code is really a malware before you remove it